# Finding non zero row number in a google sheet from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I've looked on stackoverflow and Google forums for an answer to this but couldn't quite find what I wanted.
I have numerous sheets with different names, such as "members", "officers", "trustees" etc and each one has columns for peoples names, followed by birthdates, addresses etc. (each sheet has no header). I am trying to find the number of occupied rows in each sheet from another sheet, to give the number of people. 
So, for instance, if I have a sheet called "numbers", the A1 would be the number of non-zero rows in "members", the B1 would be the same for "officers" etc.
I've referenced cells in other sheets before by doing something like =members!A14 but I don't know how to find the row number of the last row from another sheet. Can anyone help please? Ideally, I'd like this to be a formula rather than a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will count the number of non-blank cells in column A on the sheet named members.

```
=counta(members!A1:A)
```